# spring-boot cloud stream with Kafka as a stand alone library

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm trying to integrate a library based on spring-boot cloud stream with Kafka within non-spring application.

When this library is loaded within another Spring application everything works.

When I try to initialize application context with Non-spring boot enabled application and get my bean I get the following warnings and exception:

```
org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer - Cannot find '.class' file for class [class com.acme.common.library.spring.service.InstrumentIdLookupServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$59e4e4ac] - unable to determine constructor/method parameter names

org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'instrumentIdLookupServiceImpl' via constructor to bean named 'instrumentIdLookupServiceProperties'

WARN org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.acme.common.library.spring.InstrumentIdBinding': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory found for binding target type: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream among registered factories: channelFactory,messageSourceFactory

No factory found for binding target type: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream among registered factories: channelFactory,messageSourceFactory
```

```
public interface InstrumentIdBinding {
    String INSTRUMENT_IDS = "instrument-ids";

    @Input(INSTRUMENT_IDS)
    KStream<String, InstrumentIdMsg> processInstrumentId();
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.acme.common.library.spring"/>
</beans>
```

```
GenericApplicationContext ctx = new GenericApplicationContext();
final XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(ctx);
xmlReader.loadBeanDefinitions(new FileSystemResource("applicationContext-ext.xml"));
ctx.refresh();
InstrumentIdLookupService bean = ctx.getBean(InstrumentIdLookupService.class);
```

Comment: It won’t work. The binder requires spring boot auto configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Stream requires Spring Boot.